# How to center text in QGraphicsSimpleTextItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

I have a problem - I need to center text in my QGraphicsSimpleTextItem. I inherited my class from QGraphicsSimpleTextItem. Do I need to override the `paint()` method or what should I do?

I've read about `tightBoundingRect()` in `QFontMetrics`. Can I set position of tight bounding rect in QGraphicsSimpleTextItem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work.

```
void MySimpleTextItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
        QFont numberFont = QFont("Helvetica [Cronyx]", 20);
        painter->setFont(numberFont);
        painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(itemIndex));
    }
```

In my case this piece of code were to draw a number inside a QGraphicsEllipseItem, centered inside ellipse. I shaped my code a bit to fit your case, but essential point here is `painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(itemIndex));`, where you use boundingRect() along with flag Qt::AlignCenter.

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` is just big enough to hold the text, so alignment of the text **within** the item does not make sense.

That, what you might do, is to position the whole item with respect to other items. You do not need to subclass `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`. Instead, use [`QGraphicsItem::setPos`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos) to accomplish that. As a result the text will appear to be aligned in some way, e.g. centered.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody trying to do this for PyQt5 this is simple way to center text and set a hover event. Hope it helps.

```
class SimpleText(QtWidgets.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleText, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.font_family = 'Arial'
        self.font_size = 2.1


    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("black"))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("gray"))

    def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: 'QStyleOptionGraphicsItem', widget: QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None:
        custom_font = QtGui.QFont(self.font_family)
        custom_font.setPointSizeF(self.font_size)
        painter.setFont(custom_font)
        painter.drawText(self.boundingRect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.text())
```